# Only first function in header works but the last two don't in c

Tags: c

I made this header for some program functions:

```
#ifndef STRING_H_INCLUDED
#define STRING_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdio.h>

int s_length(char *test_string){      //returns string length
    int i=0;
    while(*test_string){
        i++;
        test_string++;
    }
    return i;
};

void s_insert(char *string_one){        //inserts string
    scanf("%s",string_one);
};

void s_output(char *string_one){        //outputs string
    printf("%s",string_one);
};

#endif
```

and I call the functions in the c file like 2 times each. But the last 2 of them get this:  `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘s_insert’` and `undefined reference to 's_insert'`. for both functions.

What does this mean, and what did I do wrong?

It might have to do with the main c file in which I call the functions.

main progam:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "string.h"

char *name,*surname;


void menu(){
    int choise;
    do{
        printf("1: incerici dati\n");
        printf("2: output dati\n");
        printf("3: calcola lungezza\n");
        printf("0: ecsi\n");
        printf("incerici: ");
        scanf("%d", &choise);
        printf("------------------\n");
        switch(choise){
            case 1:
                printf("String 1:");
                s_insert(name);
                printf("String 2:");
                s_insert(surname);
                printf("------------------\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                s_output(name);
                s_output(surname);
                printf("------------------\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("string 1: %s  lungezza: %d \n",name,s_length(name));
                printf("string 2: %s  lungezza: %d \n",surname,s_length(surname));
                printf("------------------\n");
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("prgram closed!!\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Errore: %d schelta invalida\n",choise);
                break;
        }
    }while(choise);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    name=malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    surname=malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

ps fot the people wondering, the printed text is italian because it's a school exercice.

Comment: why'd you put function definitions in header?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I followed a tutorial on using headers and this is how he wold me to do it

Comment: are you sure `string.h` and `main.c` are in same folder?Its working for me.Make sure you typed names correctly.

Comment: it works for me, but you need to cast the malloc result to char*

Comment: @swang Check this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc` for why you should not cast the result of malloc.

Comment: @wsang what does that mean

Comment: Don't call your header `string.h` , it's the same name as a C library header which contains, for example, strlen/strcat/etc. Rename your header to something else, like `my_string.h`

Comment: yeah no, I changed the name because the headerr is my first name which I dont want to lay around the internet so i changed it

Comment: i tried: `s_insert(&name);` instead of `s_insert(name);` but no succes

Comment: @CoderGuy: by the way this is a pure C question, you may want to edit the tag so it's not c++

Comment: I thought I deleted that but I'll take care of it now

Comment: @SantoshA neither clang nor gcc4.9 will compile it without the cast: error: assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'void *' -- I just realised I was saving the file in .cpp so it's compiled as c++, it's fine in c, but in c++ it won't compile without the cast.

Comment: This should give either an error for all three functions (including `s_length`) or for none of them. Please make sure the code is copied and pasted from code you've tried exhibiting the described behavior, and include the compiler output verbatim.

Comment: OT: This `s_insert` function is inherently broken. No matter how much memory `string_one` points to, the user could provide more input. (Look for the `gets` function which was removed from the language for exactly the same reason, for example, for further explanation.)

Comment: The problem is not in the code you are showing us

Comment: @zoska than what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled  your code in .c file and compiled it. I was hoping to get error as

`string.h : No such file or directory`

but,as string.h is also a name of standard C library compiler gave me

`[Warning] implicit declaration of function 's_insert' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Hope above explanation gives you a clue.

Most probably:

1. Your header and source are not in same folder.

OR

2. Your include path not set to correct location

OR

3.You are having other name to header than `string.h`

Note:
Copying your header code into `string.h` created by me works well.

[image]

Comment: the header is not called that way but I just called it so you guys dont know my real name

Comment: @CoderGuy try removing #ifndef in your header and check whats the result.

Comment: @CoderGuy have you stored header and source file in same folder?

Comment: can you show me your string.h file so i maybe can see a difference

Comment: @CoderGuy I copied exactly same code what you have posted in question.No any change.

Comment: that's wierd. I will try making another one and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that the `string.h` that got included was not "your" string.h but the C library's `string.h`. I'm only guessing because you didn't show us how you invoked the compiler.

You should rename your header file.

Also, you shouldn't **define** functions in a header, only **declare** them:

```
int s_length(char *test_string);      //returns string length
void s_insert(char *string_one);      //inserts string
```

The implementation should be in another c file (what you have in your header file now). Then you should build the main file and the file implementing your functions, together:

```
$ gcc -Wall -pedantic -W main.c functions.c
```

If you are still getting the `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘s_insert’` and `undefined reference to 's_insert'` messages, that means that your header (whatever its name) was not processed by the compiler. If you did not get a `fatal  error: string.h: No such file or directory` message, that means another file with the same name was found (that's why `string.h` is a bad idea for your own file). To check what files are included, add the `-H` switch to GCC (or /showIncludes if you are using Microsoft Visual Studio).

Comment: the header is not called that way but I just called it so you guys dont know my real name

Comment: so do I have to make another c file and than main.c is my main code and functions.c is the new file.

Comment: That would be the right thing to do. Your attempt with main.c and one header would work for this small example, but it's a bad habit to do it that way.